# Application support directory not found

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to write to the ApplicationSupportDirectory and for some reason the directory does not seem to exist in debug mode. Is this the expected behaviour ?. I expected this directory to exist in both Debug and Release modes.I cannot find any documentation related to this.

```
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationSupportDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as NSString
documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("demo.plist")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommended to use the `FileManager` related API to get the directory because you can create it on-the-fly if it's missing.

```
do {
    let applicationSupportDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let demoPlistURL = applicationSupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent("demo.plist")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The result `demoPlistURL` is an `URL` rather than a `String`.

Comment: Thank you , is there a reason for it to be missing ? I'm worried that it could suddenly be missing in production code as well. At the moment it works fine in RELEASE mode.

Comment: I don't know under which circumstances the directory is created or not.